# Ambiguity in case of multiple inheritance and spaceship operator in C++20

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overloading, multiple-inheritance, c++20

In the following simplified program, struct `C` inherits from two structs `A` and `B`. The former defines both spaceship `operator <=>` and less operator, the latter – only spaceship operator. Then less operation is performed with objects of class `C`:

```
#include <compare>

struct A { 
    auto operator <=>(const A&) const = default;
    bool operator <(const A&) const = default;
};
struct B { 
    auto operator <=>(const B&) const = default; 
};
struct C : A, B {};
int main() { 
    C c;
    c.operator<(c); //ok everywhere
    return c < c;   //error in GCC
}
```

The surprising moment here is that the explicit call `c.operator<(c)` succeeds in all compliers, but the similar call `c<c` is permitted by Clang but rejected in GCC:

```
error: request for member 'operator<=>' is ambiguous
<source>:8:10: note: candidates are: 'auto B::operator<=>(const B&) const'
<source>:4:10: note:                 'constexpr auto A::operator<=>(const A&) const'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xn7W9PaPc

There is a possibly related question: [GCC can't differentiate between operator++() and operator++(int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091513/gcc-cant-differentiate-between-operator-and-operatorint) . But in that question the explicit operator (++) call is rejected by all compilers, unlike this question where explicit operator call is accepted by all.

I thought that only one `operator <` is present in `C`, which was derived from `A`, and starship operator shall not be considered at all. Is it so and what compiler is right here?

Comment: Do you use a C++20 compiler?

Comment: @jacobgalam The starship operator is available since C++20. So, it cannot compile without... (Btw. it's used in the linked demo code on Compiler Explorer.)

Comment: The problem is not in the spaceship operator, the problem is in multiple inheritance, When `c < c` , you compiler gets confused by which path to follow to evaluate `<=>` operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gcc is correct here.

When you do:

```cpp
c.operator<(c);
```

You are performing name lookup on something literally named `operator<`. There is only one such function (the one in `A`) so this succeeds.

But when you do `c < c`, you're not doing lookup for `operator<`. You're doing two things:

1. a specific lookup for `c < c` which finds `operator<` candidates (member, non-member, or builtin)
2. finding all rewritten candidates for `c <=> c`

Now, the first lookup succeeds and finds the same `A::operator<` as before. But the second lookup fails - because `c <=> c` is ambiguous (between the candidates in `A` and `B`). And the rule, from [[class.member.lookup]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#class.member.lookup-6.sentence-2) is:

> The result of the search is the declaration set of `S(N,T)`.
> If it is an invalid set, the program is ill-formed.

We have an invalid set as the result of the search, so the program is ill-formed. It's not that we find nothing, it's that the whole lookup fails. Just because in this context we're looking up a rewritten candidate rather than a primary candidate doesn't matter, it's still a failed lookup.

---

And it's actually good that it fails because if we fix this ambiguous merge set issue in the usual way:

```
  struct C : A, B {
+     using A::operator<=>;
+     using B::operator<=>;
  };
```

Then our lookup would be ambiguous! Because now our lookup for the rewritten candidates finds two `operator<=>`s, so we end up with three candidates:

1. `operator<(A const&, A const&)`
2. `operator<=>(A const&, A const&)`
3. `operator<=>(B const&, B const&)`

`1` is better than `2` (because a primary candidate is better than a rewritten candidate), but `1` vs `3` is ambiguous (neither is better than the other).

So the fact that the original fails, and this one also fails, is good: it's up to you as the class author to come up with the right thing to do - since it's not obvious what that is.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, if we remove `operator <=>` from `A` then the program shall remain ill-formed since the remaining two candidates `operator<(A const&, A const&)` and `operator<=>(B const&, B const&)` are neither better than the other? But GCC accepts such program: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9rPrzfxcP

Comment: @Fedor gcc implements something slightly different than the standard rules in order to catch some other breakages.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is fixed in Clang 18: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/51528

Comment: Surprisingly, GCC also had this bug, but only in SFINAE context: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113529

Answer (score 0):

I reported the issue to Microsoft and they tell me that their and Clang behavior is right, while GCC is wrong: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/False-acceptance-of-ambiguity-in-case-of/1534112

Let me quote their answer here for completeness:

> The compiler behavior you’re observing is by design as per the resolution outlined in https://cdacamar.github.io/wg21papers/proposed/spaceship-dr.html. The reason is that the compiler will find both `A::operator<=>`, `A::operator<`, and `B::operator<=>` as possible overload resolution candidates. Because `A::operator<` does not require rewriting the expression the compiler will not consider `A::operator<=>` because `A::operator<` is declared in the same scope with the same signature so the only remaining candidates are `A::operator<` and `B::operator<=>` but since `<=>` requires rewriting the expression it is dropped later and `A::operator<` is selected. You can observe that Clang has the same behavior here: https://godbolt.org/z/M6ffr95Ej